# SVG Failure on Mac

Tags: svg

I've been through the answers [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUw9z.png) several times yet none apply to my issue, far as I can see. I'm not a coder but I can compare code side-by-side.

I make images with an iOS app then access them on my Mac via iCloud. About half the time they convert perfectly though only in Figma since Inkspace and Photoshop display every SVG as a small, black window. I'm seeking help to convert those that won't work anywhere, that in Figma say "Unable to Open" and in Inkspace do nothing at all. In Finder (Catalina) half of these open with the text "This page contains the following errors:error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error." and nothing more. Following are some screenshots that may be more meaningful. The side-by-side comparisons are titled "Working" on the left and "Failing" on the right. They are representative of every file that works and fails...each looks very much alike.

[image: Both Icontypes fail]
[image: Comparison]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post text as text and include an [mcve] of the problem as text.

Comment: Can't find any way to delete.

Comment: Is there another site where I might be more welcome?

Comment: You're welcome here. We just need you to post text as text so we can answer the question and have it be useful to others.

Comment: @Pamelane: the failing file is not a svg file. Please add more details what iOS app you're using. The invalid file might be the native editor format of you graphic app. Maybe the file wasn't exported/converted correctly as svg but instead saved in its native format.

Comment: @herrstrietzel that fits with when they break, when I've renamed them on the Mac rather than on the iPad. The iOS app is called "Mandalas" and it titles files "Mandala.mandala" with users providing a number designation after choosing between a low-res jpeg or a hi-res svg. I think I've found a way to keep from creating the broken svgs, but many of my favorite designs are now broken. I'd be most grateful for any ideas to use them.

Comment: @Pamelane: can you rename the broken files back to ".mandala" extension and try to open them in your mandala app again?

Comment: @herrstrietzel this does allow me to open the files in the iOS app, very helpful for editing. Unfortunately it doesn't allow me to open or import the files on the Mac, necessary to work with them further. Here's the text at top of failing files, in case it suggests anything: "error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty."

Comment: @Pamelane: Ok if you can open these files in your iOS app again and see the desired rendering – **export them once again to svg**. Keep in mind: applications like your mandala generator use a **custom/proprietary format**. In other words: you can't expect any other app can parse/interpret this format – actually it's pretty tricky even using quite standardized "exchange" formats like svg. If you need a more seamless workflow – check if this specific app has a MacOS sibling. Otherwise you might search for a similar app available for MacOS and iOS.

Comment: @Pamelane: For questions related to graphic applications you might indeed try to search/post on sibling channels like  [graphicdesign.stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) since they are more focused on design app related topics.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thanks so much for your help. I do want to remind that the app is providing buttons to save images AS SVG and, once done, it flashes an "exported" flag to signal as much so its not completely proprietary, or perhaps I misunderstand. I cannot do anything at all to fix a broken svg once it's broken, so no turning those back to the app or anything else. This is what I'm most eager to address as I have those images in no other form. Granted, I should probably be talking to them but your generosity is most appreciated.